# Node.js / OS X: How to notify node.js app when computer enters sleep

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

Is it possible to have OS X notify my node.js app when the computer (that node.js is running on) is entering sleep or shutting down? Seems like it should be, but I haven't been able to find anything node.js related. I did find [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html) but it's talking about Cocoa apps. Maybe I could have some other app (like Cocoa) receive the sleep notification and pass that to node.js?

I'd love to hear any suggestions that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this should be in Stack Overflow or Ask Different. But I figured this was more a programming question than an OS X specific question. Sorry if I'm in the wrong place.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [`OS`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html) module where I would expect this to be. My guess is that you could use node's [`Child Process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to spawn a shell (or some other language) script listening for this that then notifies the parent node process.

Comment: This may help http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/possible-to-run-scripts-on-sleep-and-wake

Comment: When you say "the computer", do you mean the computer that node.js is running on?  Or do you mean some other computer that is connected to it?

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry, yes the computer that node.js is running on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`nodobjc`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC) (it seems to work, but I haven't tested this very well):

```
'use strict';

const $ = require('nodobjc');

// Load the AppKit framework.
$.framework('AppKit');

// Create delegate that gets notified
let Delegate = $.NSObject.extend('Delegate');

// The function that gets called when OS X is going to sleep.
function receiveSleepNote(self, cmd, notif) {
  console.log('going to sleep');
}

Delegate.addMethod('receiveSleepNote:', 'v@:@', receiveSleepNote);
Delegate.register();

// Instantiate the delegate and set it as observer.
let delegate = Delegate('alloc')('init');
let nc       = $.NSWorkspace('sharedWorkspace')('notificationCenter');

nc(
  'addObserver', delegate,
  'selector'   , 'receiveSleepNote:',
  'name'       , $.NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification,
  'object'     , null
)

// Set up the runloop.
let app = $.NSApplication('sharedApplication');
function runLoop() {
  let pool = $.NSAutoreleasePool('alloc')('init');
  try {
    app('nextEventMatchingMask', $.NSAnyEventMask.toString(),
        'untilDate',             $.NSDate('distantFuture'),
        'inMode',                $.NSDefaultRunLoopMode,
        'dequeue',               1);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('run loop error', e.message);
  };
  pool('drain');
  process.nextTick(runLoop);
}
runLoop();
```

Other types of notifications that you can observe can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification).

Comment: For the record, This script would prevent the rest of my node.js app from running. But I was able to create a child process like @Matthew Herbst had suggested which runs this script and notifies my primary app when sleep is coming. This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @tylermackenzie yeah, the `runLoop()` should be properly "asyncified" to make it work better with other code running, didn't think of that.

Comment: is that easily done? Also I was able to make it watch for multiple types of notifications by calling `Delegate.addMethod` and `nc()` several times and replacing `NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification` and  creating a new "selector" and callback, it seems to work, would that be considered an good method?

Comment: Try replacing `runLoop` with [this file](https://github.com/TooTallNate/NodObjC/blob/master/examples/EventLoop.js). How to use it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/shanewholloway/161a4eaf46724eacc03b#file-testmetadatasearch-js-L13-L17). Adding new selectors and notifications like that should work just fine.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. couldn't really get it working, I think it's a little over my head to figure out. But everything seems to be working so long as I run it in a child process.

Comment: @tylermackenzie. Can you please share your code showing how you created the child process. Like you said I am able to receive notifications but the code is blocking. I am trying to fork a child process from node webkit but getting spawn eaAccess error.